# Numpy isin on an array of faces

Tags: python, numpy

I have a mesh which is made up of vertices and faces.

A face is an array of three vertex indices.

I have a sub-list of these vertices, and I wish to find the subset of faces which are made up of these vertices.

my faces array is a list of faces.

Here is my slow method:

```
using_faces_list = []

for face in faces:
    if face[0] in using_vert_ids and \
        face[1] in using_vert_ids and \
        face[2] in using_vert_ids:

        using_faces_list.append([vert_to_using_vert_id[id] for id in face])
```

Is there a faster way of doing that, maybe using np.isin?

Comment: It strikes me I could find all possible faces of the subset of verts by doing:
combs = combinations(using_vert_ids, 3)
and then do faces = faces[np.isin(faces, combs, axis=1)] 
but that feels quite maximalist

Answer (score 0):

This worked, and is quite elegant:

```
    faces_t = np.transpose(faces)

    mask = np.isin(faces_t[0], using_vert_ids) & np.isin(faces_t[1], using_vert_ids) & np.isin(faces_t[2], using_vert_ids)

    using_faces = faces[mask]

    using_faces = [[vert_to_using_vert_id[f[0]], vert_to_using_vert_id[f[1]], vert_to_using_vert_id[f[2]]] for f in using_faces]        

    using_faces = np.array(using_faces)
```